# add new SQL Table to Identity 2.0 data context

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I've been building an ASP.NET MVC5 Web App with Identity 2.0 hosted in Azure (using [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics) and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Rol) for guidance on implementing Identity 2.0), and have encountered an issue that I'm hoping someone can help with.

My issue ultimately stems from the need to add additional SQL Tables, and not knowing the proper way to handle this from a data context perspective. With Identity 2.0 fully working and hosted in my web app's Azure SQL, the next goal was to create a new custom table for storing some additional data. Creating the new class in my Model, adding scaffolding and creating a controller were all easy enough, but what I can't figure out is the data context.

What I had originally done (which seemed to be working for awhile, until trying to enable Code-First Migrations and inadvertently dropping my Identity 2.0 tables) was create a second data context inheriting from DbContext, as such (please ignore the red squiggles under "WepApp", changed this to something generic for purpose of sharing):

[image: Please ignore red squiggles under "WebApp". Changed this to something generic for purpose of sharing.]

I then used this new data context in the Controller for this class, as shown below:

[image]

While this worked to get the job done at first, when trying to update this new table by adding additional columns I inadvertently dropped my Identity 2.0 tables, and now get "multiple data context" errors whenever I try to do any migration action, preventing me from recreating them. My suspicion, although I'm far from certain, is that I should have integrated my new table into the same data context as the Identity 2.0 tables, since they are different tables in the same database.

Can anyone offer any advice for properly adding additional tables to the database housing an Identity 2.0 system? In particular, how should this be handled from a data context perspective? I'm somewhat desperate right now as I've completely lost my Identity 2.0 backend tables, and am struggling to get them recreated. Thanks.

Comment: This should be as simple as adding the `DbSet` to your `ApplicationDbContext`, and then adding a migration that will create your new table.  I guess the migration that was created for your `CustomerProfileContext` analysed the database and determined that you were dropping all the Identity tables.  So, is your question on how to fix an existing database by migrating the tables across to a single context, or how to get this working from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you need to be adding the DbContext apart from the "DefaultConnection" (note that you'll need to add another connectionString in your webconfig file):

```
public class CustProfileContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CustProfile> CustProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

or alternatively, moving your DbSet statement to ApplicationDbContext like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }



    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApp.Models.CustProfile> CustProfiles { get; set; }


}
```

After doing one of those, add a new migration and take a look at the configuration.cs file to make sure that Entity Framework is adding the table appropriately.

Comment: Thanks scurrie and Brendan. While my issue extended beyond this, moving my DbSet statement into ApplicationDbContext definitely helped and was just the guidance that I was looking for.

Comment: No sweat @ssmolen. For future reading you might take a look at [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/03/asp-net-identity-with-the-entity-framework.aspx) article on Identity or take a look at the docs [here](http://www.asp.net/identity)

Comment: Exactly what I needed!